# jQuery to target each #hdid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to clean up this function to target individual `#hdid`. I'm also using `$this`, but with no success.

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $(".delete").click(function() {
                $('#load').fadeIn();
                var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
               // var id = $this.(".delete").val();
               // var string = id ;
               //  console.log(id);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete-class.php",
                    data: {hdid: $('#hdid').val()},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(){
                        commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                        $('#load').fadeOut();
                        //console.log(string);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refactor your code a bit you can do it this way. I'm also making the assumption that you mean `.hdid` instead of `#hdid` there should only be one hdid per page if it's really an ID and not a CLASS. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/p5dTt/1/) a quick sample if you're interested in seeing it in action.

```
<script>
            var DeleteClass = function(hdid){
                $.ajax{
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete-class.php",
                    data: {hdid: hdid.val()},
                    cache:false,
                    success:function(){
                       hdid.parent().slideUp('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
                    }
            }


    $(function() {
        $(".delete").click(function() {
            $('#load').fadeIn();
            $(this).children(".hdid").each(function(){
                DeleteClass($(this));
            });
            $('#load').fadeOut();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `DeleteClass` instead of `deleteClass`? By convention, only Constructor functions should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Also, please cache you selectors!

Comment: no reason, I don't really write a lot of javascript, so I don't know all the conventions. And I realize there's several things I could do to make it a little better. But the gist of it was the each function on hdid.

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually want to do $(this) instead of $this. $this is a reserved word in PHP, not in JS/Jquery, so in your case it's undefined

$(this) on the other hand is the JQuery object of which your callback is a method of (in your case the clicked .delete element)

Just type $(this).val() and you will get the value of the clicked element.

Comment: that doesn't answer his question...